# NASM - Get number of items in stack

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to figure out how to get the number of items in the stack by subtracting the sp register with bp. What am I doing wrong? I get totally wrong result

```
MOV bp, 0x7E00
MOV sp, bp

PUSH 'A'
PUSH 'B'
PUSH 'C'

POP bx
MOV al, bl
CALL _printchar

POP bx
MOV al, bl
CALL _printchar

MOV bx, sp
SUB bx, bp
ADD bx, 48 ;To get ascii number
MOV al, bl
CALL _printchar
```

This is the output:

CB.

Comment: Can you post the output?

Comment: @1.618 I added the output

Comment: Suggestion: do not put a specific number in SP.  You're asking for disaster.   If this works for you; great.  There are a million other (way safer) ways to find out where the stack actually is.  Again, if this is working for you; duh; okay. I see lots of worries.

Comment: @User.1 Well, I am trying to create an own operating system, so I need to have it on a specific position so that it does not overwrite my code

Comment: @ErikW: I encourage you, in this instance if no others, to trust the Linker. He is very good at that; really he is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A really confusing thing about the stack is that it grows down.

Compared to most people's mental image of a stack, the stack you work with in assembly is "upside down".  The "bottom" of the stack has the highest memory address, and the "top" has the lowest.  When you push 2 bytes onto the stack, 2 bytes are *subtracted* from the stack pointer, not added to it.  (If you think about it in terms of memory partitioning, this is actually safer)

So the result of your SUB was -2, which is '.' in ascii. You can't just switch the operands around, because the result needs to go into the first operand, so it should be a general purpose register. Instead, alter the MOV operations before the SUB.

Comment: Just curious: why is the result -2?  There are three PUSHes and 2 POPs.  I expected -1.

Comment: Because you're pushing/popping 2 bytes each time. A push is always the same size, regardless of what value you're pushing.

Comment: Method will also fail when stack frame > 9 bytes.

Comment: what do you mean by "grow down"?